# Xcode - UISwitch come back after change state

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiswitch

I have a great problem with an UISwitch on my app, this switch change its state after a read function of a variable in a Timer (I'm obliged because it is on a webserver); if this value is 0 it switch on OFF, the problem born in this moment because if I switch on ON by touch it turns first on OFF state and then after it reads the value (that I change with the touch) by the Timer it comes to YES. 
I would like to delete this problem... in case, is there a better solution to read (or send by) a web server value in a javascript function?
Thank at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to follow. Whats your question? Probably you just need to to an additional if check: `if(mySwitch.on == YES) { mySwitch.on = NO; }` so it will only turned off, if it was active before!?

Comment: perhaps put a new helper variable in the code (eg `BOOL userDidChangeValue`) and block the first timer update after that? i don't get your setup stil.. perhaps you can show some code. edit your question to make it more clear.